# Adding new column with name as combination of variable and string

Tags: r

I have a function that defines a list of numbers.  I would then like to add new columns to a pre-existing dataframe, with the new column names coming from the above list, and the value corresponding to those column names.

I'm able to achieve this.
Existing dataframe:

```
ID  Code    Value
1   C       5
1   C       7
1   C       15
1   C       20
1   C       30
```

I then define the list:

```
Increments = c("5","15","30") # create list as strings for new column names

for (i in Increments) {df[[i]] <- as.numeric(i)} # add new columns, fill columns with numeric value identical to column name
```

Which produces:

```
ID  Code    Value   5   15  30
1   C       5       5   15  30
1   C       7       5   15  30
1   C       15      5   15  30
1   C       20      5   15  30
1   C       30      5   15  30
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to create new columns named [[i]]Check (5Check, 15Check, 30Check, etc.) that subtract the relevant columns' values from the numbers in column "Value".

Expected Output:

```
ID  Code    Value   5   15  30  5Check  15Check 30Check
1   C       5       5   15  30  0       10      25
1   C       7       5   15  30  -2      8       23
1   C       15      5   15  30  -10     0       15
1   C       20      5   15  30  -15     -5      10
1   C       30      5   15  30  -25     -15     0
```

I've tried:

```
for (i in Increments) {df[[i]]Seconds <- df[[i]] - df$Value}
```

but receive the following error:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "for (i in Increments) {df[[i]]Seconds"
```

As far as I can understand, the problem is with df[[i]]Seconds, as when i remove "[[i]]", it works fine (but doesn't loop through all the variables.
I've tried variations of paste, but can't get it to work...

Comment: You have to assign the column _names_ separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do this :

```
#Create a list of Increments
Increments = list(5, 15, 30)
#Create column names
cols <- paste0('col', seq_along(Increments))
#Add Increments column to dataframe
df[cols] <- Increments
#Subtract `Value` from `cols` column
df[paste0('Check', Increments)] <- df[cols] - df$Value
df

#  ID Code Value col1 col2 col3 Check5 Check15 Check30
#1  1    C     5    5   15   30      0      10      25
#2  1    C     7    5   15   30     -2       8      23
#3  1    C    15    5   15   30    -10       0      15
#4  1    C    20    5   15   30    -15      -5      10
#5  1    C    30    5   15   30    -25     -15       0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Code = c("C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C"), Value = c(5L, 7L, 15L, 20L, 30L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
sapply(as.numeric(Increments), function(i) i - df$Value)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0   10   25
#[2,]   -2    8   23
#[3,]  -10    0   15
#[4,]  -15   -5   10
#[5,]  -25  -15    0
```

or

```
df[Increments] <- sapply(as.numeric(Increments), function(i) i - df$Value)


#  ID Code Value   5  15 30
#1  1    C     5   0  10 25
#2  1    C     7  -2   8 23
#3  1    C    15 -10   0 15
#4  1    C    20 -15  -5 10
#5  1    C    30 -25 -15  0
```

Comment: Thanks Sotos.  This gets the right calculation, but doesn't add "Check" to the column names.

Comment: You can simply do `df[paste0('Check', Increments)] <- ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
library(tidyverse)
incr <- list(5, 15, 30) %>% set_names(paste0("col", seq_along(.)))

map_dfc(incr, ~ .x - df$Value) %>% 
  purrr::set_names(nm = paste0("Check", incr)) %>% 
  bind_cols(df, incr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who answered.  I've also made a small change in my original attempt, which works.
Instead of

```
Increments = c("5","15","30")
```

I've defined

```
Increments = c("Check5","Check15","Check30")
```

Then, in order to generate the columns, I've defined:

```
for (i in Increments) {df[[i]] <- as.numeric(gsub("Check","",i)) - df$Value}
```